# Application crashing HTC Explorer A310e when using Gson

Tags: android, gson

I am getting this error using a HTC Explorer A310e, but it works fine with other devices. What can be the real issue?

```
03-25 12:23:37.553: ERROR/EmbeddedLogger(178): App crashed! Process: com.consors.android.de
03-25 12:23:37.553: ERROR/EmbeddedLogger(178): App crashed! Package: com.consors.android.de v4 (1.0.3.9)
03-25 12:23:37.553: ERROR/EmbeddedLogger(178): Error getting package label: com.consors.android.de
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.htc.server.embedded.EmbeddedLogger.onHandleApplicationCrash(EmbeddedLogger.java:59)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerService.java:7739)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:1033)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1657)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
03-25 12:23:37.553: ERROR/EmbeddedLogger(178): Application Label: <ERROR>
03-25 12:23:37.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(538): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapterFactory
        at com.consors.android.auxilary.GsonRequestResponseHandler.getInstance(GsonRequestResponseHandler.java:26)
        at com.consors.android.ui.watchlist.WebWatchList.subscribeWatchListsUrlRequest(WebWatchList.java:293)
        at com.consors.android.ui.AbsSnapShotActivity.sendWatchListRequest(AbsSnapShotActivity.java:2105)
        at com.consors.android.ui.AbsSnapShotActivity.onActivityResult(AbsSnapShotActivity.java:422)
        at com.consors.android.de.ui.SnapShotActivity.onActivityResult(SnapShotActivity.java:198)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3016)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3072)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1084)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the code that causes the exception:

```
public static GsonRequestResponseHandler getInstance() {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        INSTANCE = new GsonRequestResponseHandler();
        gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ArrayAdapterFactory()).create();
    }
   return  INSTANCE;

}
```

the custom TypeAdapter definition:

```
public class ArrayAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })

public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> type) { 
  TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = null;
  try {
      if (type.getRawType() == ArrayList.class)
      {  
          typeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(
                  (Class) ((ParameterizedType) type.getType())
                          .getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
      }
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return typeAdapter;
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you post some code? Maybe the relevant lines:

        at com.consors.android.auxilary.GsonRequestResponseHandler.getInstance(GsonRequestResponseHandler.java:26)

Comment: please find relavant part of code i have pasted it above

Comment: It seems to me that you have deployed an old version of Gson on that phone (< 2.1). In 2.1 registerTypeAdapterFactory was added to builder. But just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this question is 7 months old this might still help other with the same bug.

Some HTC phones have an outdated version of Gson in their system classpath. The (newer) version of the Gson JAR that is included in your app is therefore ignored.

I know of two possible solutions, neither of which is particularly convenient:
1) Work with the old version of Gson. This is probably a bad idea, since you might need some of the new features and bugfixes from later versions. Also, future HTC phones might ship with a different Gson version, so this approach is not very robust.
2) Repackage the version of Gson included in your application, as described in https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-on-android